# Иконка в инпуте не отображаеться

Tags: html, css

Не отображаеться backround-image в инпуте. В чем проблема?

```
    <input readonly type="text" name="people" class="people-input">
```

```
.people-input { height: 38px; font-size: 15px; width: 236px; border: 0.8px solid rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.37); color: 1f1e1ef5; font-family: 'Helvetica';  font-weight: 400; background-color: fbf7f7; background-image: url(images/icons/arrow.png);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариантов может быть несколько. Например, у Вас просто неправильно указан путь к файлу с картинкой: url(images/icons/arrow.png).

Напомню, что если css-файл лежит не в корне, а, скажем, в папке css, то путь к картинкам должен начинаться с двух точек и слеша (т.е. Вы сначала выходите из папки css в корень, а уже потом заходите в папку images): url(../images/icons/arrow.png)

Если же путь верный, то проблема может быть в размере картинки. Если она большая (я для своего примера специально взял большую), то в инпуте будет виден только её левый верхний край. Чтобы была видна вся картинка, нужно указать background-size: contain. А чтобы она не репитилась, background-repeat: no-repeat.

```css
.people-input {
  height: 38px;
  font-size: 15px;
  width: 236px;
  border: 0.8px solid rgba(31, 31, 31, 0.37);
  font-family: 'Helvetica'; 
  font-weight: 400;
  background-color: #fbf7f7;
  background-image: url(https://www.clipartmax.com/png/middle/189-1898460_curved-arrow-to-the-right-clip-art-download-curved-arrow-pointing-right.png);
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
```

```html
<input readonly type="text" name="people" class="people-input">
```

Comment: спасибо! действительно помогло)

Comment: @unknown, а что в итоге было - путь или размер картинки?

Comment: размер картинки